# In-place vs Return New design patterns in C

Tags: c, arrays, design-patterns, memory-management

In coming from higher level languages, I'm trying to rebase myself by learning c.  I'm trying to understand pointers and memory allocation (something I've never had to think about before).

Code I'm trying

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int array[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52 };

    printf("\nShuffling...\n\n");
    shuffle(array, sizeof(array)/sizeof(int));

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < sizeof(array)/sizeof(int); i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", array[i]);
    }

}

int shuffle(int *shuffle_array, int length)
{
    int i, j, newArray[length];
    for(i = 0, j = length; i < length; j--, i++)
    {
        newArray[i] = shuffle_array[j];
    }

    shuffle_array = newArray;
}
```

**First**, this doesn't work and I'm trying to figure out why the array isn't reversed on printing.

**Second**, comparing the concept of in-place editing vs returning a new item within c using `malloc()` and `free()`.

Comment: 1st: newArray is allocated on the stack and will be freed after leaving shuffle -> shuffle_array will point to garbage. 2nd you are handing over a pointer and not a reference to a pointer (or a pointer to a pointer), hence your result will not be given back to the main -> no changes after shuffle.

Comment: cool, but then why does it print out in the original order properly then? if it points to garbage?

Comment: Since you use C99 (else you wouldn't be allowed to declare a variable in the heart of a function) you should also declare your for loop counters like that: `for (int i = 0, j = length;...)`.  Also, `shuffle` doesn't return anything although you declared it as returning an `int`.

Comment: I'm just using gcc on OSX, so should I be declaring variables before anything else?

Comment: The compiler doesn't matter.  And no, you don't have to declare all variables at the head of the function, since you use *variable length arrays* (and they are only available in ANSI C99).  You would have to use `{cm}alloc()` to have arrays of a variable length in C < 99 and thats even better, since you can't detect if you ran out of memory with C99 *variable-length arrays*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When your function exits then your locally defined array drops out of scope and hence no longer exists.

You ought to memcpy back over the shuffle_array ...

```
memcpy( shuffle_array, newArray, length * sizeof( int ) );
```

Furthermore you are also starting your read off the end of shuffle_array.  The last element in the array is "length -1".

***Edit***: Reading off the end of the array won't necessarily cause a problem.  Its just that what you are doing is undefined behaviour.

The reason you see the same data come back out as you put in is because you don't actually change the data at all.

TBH for reversing an array a much better algorithm is to start at both ends and swap the data over.  You could do that as follows:

```
for(i = 0, j = (length - 1); i < j; j--, i++)
{
    int temp = shuffle_array[i];
    shuffle_array[i] = shuffleArray[j];
    shuffle_array[j] = temp;
}
```

This way you totally avoid the need for a seperate array and that final copyback.  You also save a load of stack memory.  Score all round in my opinion.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, could you provide an example?

Comment: and if that is the case, why is it printing it in the original order and not giving me a scope error?

Comment: @jondavidjohn You're not doing anything illegal with the language, it's just that you're not doing what you think you're doing.

Comment: This looks a lot like a Java example I saw earlier today.

Comment: That's because you change the local variable `shuffle_array` of `shuffle`, not the array `array` of `main`.

Comment: Thanks! learned a lot, really enjoying being closer to the metal with this stuff.

Comment: @jondavidjohn yes, you'll learn a lot more about how computers really work with C which will make you program better in every language. Don't get discouraged when/if things get hard, just keep at it and you'll be better for it.

Answer (score 8):

Inside `shuffle`, you are creating an array called `newArray` on the stack (which means it will be deallocated when the function ends).

You are then putting each item from `shuffle_array` into `newArray` backwards.

Then you are making the pointer `shuffle_array`, a local variable (which means changes to it are not reflected outside the function), point to the first element of `newArray`. This doesn't change anything outside `shuffle` because `shuffle_array` is a local variable.

After the function returns, nothing has happened to anything outside the function. This is because you are just modifying the local data withing `shuffle`.

To shuffle the array (or reverse it, or do anything to it) you have to modify it directly instead of modifying a copy. So it should be

```
int tmp = shuffle_array[i];
shuffle_array[i] = shuffle_array[j];
shuffle_array[j] = tmp;
```

So that you swap the two values of the array elements you're on. Even though `shuffle_array` is a temporary variable, it points to the block of memory in `main`, so that modifying that memory is visible even after the function returns.

You can visualise it like this:

in `main`:

```
array  - - - - 
               \
                \
                 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...,  52 };
```

when `shuffle` is called:

```
array  - - - - 
               \
                \
                 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...,  52
                /
               /
              /
shuffle_array

newArray - - -
              \
               52, ..., 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
```

Then when you do

```
shuffle_array = newArray;
```

It looks like

```
array  - - - - 
               \
                \
                 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...,  52



shuffle_array -
               \
newArray - - -  |
              \ /
               52, ..., 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
```

Then `shuffle` returns, and everything goes back to just

```
array  - - - - 
               \
                \
                 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...,  52
```

Answer (score 2):

newArray is allocated on the stack and will be freed after leaving shuffle -> shuffle_array will point to garbage.

You are handing over a pointer and not a reference to a pointer (or a pointer to a pointer), hence your result will not be given back to the main -> no changes after shuffle.

How about this solution:

```
//note, the returned array needs to be freed using free();
int *newShuffledArray(int *shuffle_array, int length)
{
    int i, j;
    int *newArray = malloc(length * sizeof(int));
    for(i = 0, j = length-1; i < length-1; j--, i++)
    {
        newArray[i] = shuffle_array[j];
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

Comment: While I don't like the idea of managing memory if I can avoid it, I appreciate the alternate approach, useful info, learned a lot thanks!

Comment: @jondavidjohn that is totally correct and the right idea of approaching the issue. I just wanted to point this alternative out for making sure you see its mechanics. The best solutions for your particular issue were given by Seth and Goz.

Comment: I do really appreciate it, dealing with raw memory and pointers is getting me turned around sometimes, but in a good way!

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, this will be much more efficient (I prefer code solutions).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void shuffle(int *shuffle_array, int length)
{
        int i, j, tmp;
        for (i = 0, j = length - 1; i < j; ++i, --j) {
                tmp = shuffle_array[i];
                shuffle_array[i] = shuffle_array[j];
                shuffle_array[j] = tmp;
        }
}

int main(void)
{
        int i, array[] = {
                1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
                11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
                21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30,
                31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40,
                41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50,
                51, 52
        }, length = sizeof(array) / sizeof(int);
        shuffle(array, length);
        for (i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
                printf("%d\n", array[i]);
        }
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

As other have mentioned, the problem with your program was that you assigned your result to a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

You don't change anything at all. You only set a local variable, so, what did you expect? ;)

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(int* a) {
    ++a;
}

int main(void) {
    int array[3] = {1,2,3};
    foo(array);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        printf("%d\n", array[i]); // results in 1\n2\n3\n, not 2\n3\nSegmentation fault\n
}
```

Comment: I find it interesting how my (correct) answer gets downvoted while a wrong answer is being accepted by the interrogator and being upvoted 4 times.

Comment: You're not alone. I think down votes should print who down voted. I saw this question -- at least I think I saw it -- earlier in the day as Java code with the same question, but I cannot remember if it was the same poster. You probably got down voted because yours and my answers could be construed as comments.

Answer (score -3):

1) You are assigning from an array on the stack. That data won't be there when the function returns.

2) I am curious as to why

```
shuffle_array = newArray
```

is used. It almost seems you are thinking there are copy constructor associated with arrays. This is not a criticsm, but is the result of my own curiosity. However, that assignment won't work, because you are assigning the address of an array on the stack to the array pointer that was passed into the function.

3) You would need to assign the local arrays' values back to the array passed in using a for loop or a memcpy.

Comment: Nobody owes you a comment for downvoting. That isn't how the system is designed or intended to work.

Comment: Your first paragraph (about the "array pointer values") is very unclear. I'm not sure what's your point there. It's also not clear what the "You cannot do this in C" refers to, the preceding paragraph or the following code segment. The quoted code does not assign element 0. Also, you can't assign arrays in C++.

Comment: It's not assigning to the first element of the array, but the pointer stored in the `shuffle_array` variable is replaced by a pointer to the array stored in `newArray`.